# Application classNotFound exception after Update on Play

Tags: android, dalvik

In my debug console:

```
Process: app.source.getcontact, PID: 5627
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.source.getcontact.MyApplication
                  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:578)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4680)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:150)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.source.getcontact.MyApplication
                  at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.createRealApplication(BootstrapApplication.java:220)
                  at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.attachBaseContext(BootstrapApplication.java:239)
                  at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:187)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:998)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:982)
                  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:573)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4680) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.source.getcontact.MyApplication
                  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
                  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285)
                  at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.createRealApplication(BootstrapApplication.java:209)
                  at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.attachBaseContext(BootstrapApplication.java:239) 
                  at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:187) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:998) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:982) 
                  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:573) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4680) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "app.source.getcontact.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/app.source.getcontact-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/app.source.getcontact-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 
                  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285) 
                  at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.createRealApplication(BootstrapApplication.java:209) 
                  at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.attachBaseContext(BootstrapApplication.java:239) 
                  at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:187) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:998) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:982) 
                  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:573) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4680) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "app.source.getcontact.MyApplication" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/app.source.getcontact/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/app.source.getcontact-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                  at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
                  at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:62)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                        ... 19 more
                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: app.source.getcontact.MyApplication
                  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                            ... 20 more
               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

First one is my debug device debug console. Now I will add developer console anr report

```
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/serrano3gxx/serrano3g:4.4.2/KOT49H/I9190XXUCOD2:user/release-keys'
Revision: '5'
pid: 17423, tid: 17445, name: AsyncTask #2  >>> ****.*****.****** <<<
signal 16 (SIGSTKFLT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
    r0 41c55078  r1 41c55078  r2 41c55078  r3 61d44f86
    r4 41c55078  r5 5cc79e9c  r6 5cac71e8  r7 000084f4
    r8 417def80  r9 00000005  sl 00000003  fp 42a8d1c0
    ip 64ca5d64  sp 629b3c30  lr 6534c9bb  pc 417e9aec  cpsr 200b0010
    d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
    d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
    d4  e1c97466582e7bdf  d5  bf55596a4c1f5b56
    d6  5cc5f9ab3da651f2  d7  f8e475e852222227
    d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
    d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    d16 57d821b857d82180  d17 57d8222857d821f0
    d18 57d81f1857d81ee0  d19 57d81f8857d81f50
    d20 57d81ff857d81fc0  d21 57de92a857d82030
    d22 57de907057d820a0  d23 57d8214857d82110
    d24 3fc74721cad6b0ed  d25 3fc2f112df3e5244
    d26 40026bb1bbb55516  d27 0000000000000000
    d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
    d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
    scr 60000010

backtrace:
    #00  pc 0002baec  /system/lib/libdvm.so (javaLangString_equals(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, JValue*)+12)
    #01  pc 000039b9  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)

code around pc:
    417e9acc e3a00000 e8bd8010 fa0071e8 e1a00004  
    417e9adc e8bd8010 e92d4010 e2504000 0a000025  
    417e9aec e1540001 0a00001e e3510000 0a000003  
    417e9afc e5942000 e5913000 e1520003 0a000005  
    417e9b0c e59d1008 e3a04001 e3a00000 e5810000  
    417e9b1c e1a00004 e8bd8010 e5942014 e5910014  
    417e9b2c e1520000 1afffff5 e594c010 e594e008  
    417e9b3c e5914008 e5911010 e28e0010 e2843010  
    417e9b4c e080008c e3a04001 e0831081 ebffd1ba  
    417e9b5c e59dc008 e2702001 33a02000 e58c2000  
    417e9b6c eaffffea e59d3008 e3a04001 e1a00004  
    417e9b7c e5834000 e8bd8010 fa0071bc eaffffe3  
    417e9b8c e3500000 13510000 e92d4038 13a03000  
    417e9b9c 03a03001 0a000016 e1500001 0a000018  
    417e9bac e5903014 e5912014 e590c010 e0534002  
    417e9bbc e591e008 e5905008 e5911010 41a02003  

code around lr:
    6534c998 f8df6a81 f8df2080 b4903074 4070f8df  
    6534c9a8 0001ea4f ea4f6129 616a0102 3c08f845  
    6534c9b8 b00247a0 f8dfb918 f7fc0054 6934ec82  
    6534c9c8 2c00612c e005d1e0 f8dfde00 6ef1003c  
    6534c9d8 1c2d4788 4300e000 47806e70 61d44f92  
    6534c9e8 4300e000 47806e70 61d44ec8 00000001  
    6534c9f8 00000001 00000000 57ddbae0 005b0105  
    6534ca08 00000001 00000000 61d44f7e 61d44f86  
    6534ca18 417e9ae0 41c55078 64c18470 f85f0048  
    6534ca28 68010008 60013101 68e969a8 6241b150  
    6534ca38 f04f6a41 42910280 60e9612a 800cf000  
    6534ca48 de00e004 0038f8df 47886ef1 fbe0e000  
    6534ca58 47806e70 58b0e488 4300e000 47806e70  
    6534ca68 58b0e562 00000002 00000000 00000000  
    6534ca78 57cffe20 000e0104 00000001 00000000  
    6534ca88 58b0e478 64c18474 f85f0034 68010008
```

When I make new publishing on play debveloper console i getting last report.Can any one knows about this issue. My application works perfectly 600 k devices but I getting 5 or 6 device this error. Have you any idea about this error?

Comment: do you have Proguard rules enabled?

Comment: No i havent proquard rules.Is it makes this errors?.I got when i clear app cache data from settings  for debug console.